# How can I create a sequence in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have created a table in sqlite.
There are two fields: `pk_categoryid`,`category_name`.
I want to enter only one value from the user side.
So, how can I create a sequence?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69088585/1070129) for how to create a sequence for a non-primary key field in SQLite.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you mean that you want the primary key to be autogenerated, then look at `AUTOINCREMENT` when creating your table:

- [SQLite CREATE TABLE syntax](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

Comment: If you don't care that deleted primary keys may be reused for subsequent rows, then you don't need the AUTOINCREMENT keyword (you can just do `pk_categoryid integer primary key`). [Using AUTOINCREMENT prevents id reuse but with an algorithm that has more overhead](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Answer (score 10):

```
create table Categories (
    pk_categoryid integer primary key autoincrement, 
    category_name text
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE categories
(
    pk_categoryid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    category_name TEST
);

INSERT INTO categories (category_name) VALUES (//your value);
```

Answer (score 0):

For PK AUTOINCREMENT, remember that you need to `INSERT` with `NULL` as in:

```
f="tmp.sqlite"
rm -f "$f"
sqlite3 "$f" 'create table t(id integer primary key, x integer)'
sqlite3 "$f" 'insert into t values (NULL, 10), (NULL, 20), (NULL, 30)'
sqlite3 "$f" 'select * from t'
```

which outputs:

```
1|10
2|20
3|30
```

Googlers may also be interested in the [`generate_series` table-valued function](https://www.sqlite.org/series.html) which loops over number ranges, e.g.:

```
f="tmp.sqlite"
rm -f "$f"
sqlite3 "$f" 'create table t(x integer)'
sqlite3 "$f" 'insert into t select value as x from generate_series(1,4)'
sqlite3 "$f" 'select * from t'
```

which outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Tested on SQLite 3.40.1, Ubuntu 23.04.