# SQLite auto-increment non-primary key field

Tags: sql, sqlite, auto-increment

Is it possible to have a non-primary key to be auto-incremented with every insertion?

For example, I want to have a log, where every log entry has a primary key (for internal use), and a revision number ( a INT value that I want to be auto-incremented).

As a workaround, this could be done with a sequence, yet I believe that sequences are not supported in SQLite.

Comment: You can use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger to emulate a sequence in SQLite. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69088585/1070129) for details.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do select max(id)+1 when you do the insertion.

For example:

`INSERT INTO Log (id, rev_no, description)
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM log), 'rev_Id', 'some description')`

Note that this will fail on an empty table since there won't be a record with `id` is 0 but you can either add a first dummy entry or change the sql statement to this:

`INSERT INTO Log (id, rev_no, description)
VALUES ((SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0) + 1 FROM Log), 'rev_Id', 'some description')`

Comment: I used the dummy entry. and after real data was added to the table, I deleted it.

Comment: The second statement didn't work for me. No such keyword as `ISNULL`. This one did:

`INSERT INTO Log (id, rev_no, description) VALUES ((SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0)) + 1 FROM Log), 'rev_Id', 'some description')`

Comment: @DamianHickey thank you for the correction. `ISNULL` is from MS SQL Server which obviously doesn't work on SQLite.

Comment: For future readers: The above snippet has 1 extra closing bracket on IFNULL. It should be like this: ` INSERT INTO Log (id, rev_no, description) VALUES ((SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0) + 1 FROM Log), 'rev_Id', 'some description') `

Comment: @pedja edited in - you can remove your comment and (I'll try to remember to remove mine :)

Answer (score 6):

SQLite creates a unique row id (rowid) automatically. This field is usually left out when you use "select * ...", but you can fetch this id by using "select rowid,* ...". Be aware that according to the SQLite documentation, they discourage the use of autoincrement.

```
create table myTable ( code text, description text );
insert into myTable values ( 'X', 'some descr.' );
select rowid, * from myTable;
```

:: Result will be;
1|X|some descr.

If you use this id as a foreign key, you can export rowid - AND import the correct value in order to keep data integrity;

```
insert into myTable values( rowid, code text, description text ) values
( 1894, 'X', 'some descr.' );
```

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer, I never knew there is the hidden `rowid` field, thank you. I guess there is really no need create additional `id` field to keep track of auto-incremented ids.

Comment: rowid can be reused after delete, so it is not monotonic and cannot be used as a replace for autoincrement

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `AFTER INSERT` [trigger](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to emulate a sequence in SQLite (but note that numbers might be reused if rows are deleted). This will make your `INSERT INTO` statement a lot easier.

In the following example, the `revision` column will be auto-incremented (unless the `INSERT INTO` statement explicitly provides a value for it, of course):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    revision INTEGER,
    description TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER auto_increment_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON test
    WHEN new.revision IS NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE test
        SET revision = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(revision), 0) + 1 FROM test)
        WHERE id = new.id;
    END;
```

Now you can simply insert a new row like this, and the `revision` column will be auto-incremented:

```
INSERT INTO test (description) VALUES ('some description');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trigger (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) that checks the previous highest value and then increments it, or if you are doing your inserts through in a stored procedure, put that same logic in there.

Comment: so... if I understand correctly, 
`CREATE TRIGGER update_revision INSERT OF single_string ON data 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE data SET revision = (SELECT max(revision) from data ) + 1 WHERE single_string = ?
  END;` is the right syntax?

Comment: Not sure about the syntax as I have not used SQLite, but you have the right idea there.  Give it a go and see what happens :)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very similar to Icarus's so I no need to mention it.

You can use Icarus's solution in a more advanced way if needed. Below is an example of seat availiabilty table for a train reservation system.

```
insert into Availiability (date,trainid,stationid,coach,seatno)
    values (
        '11-NOV-2013',
        12076,
        'SRR',
        1,
        (select max(seatno)+1
            from Availiability
            where date='11-NOV-2013'
                and trainid=12076
                and stationid='SRR'
                and coach=1)
    );
```