# AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY - SQLite & Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, auto-increment, parse-error

I'm trying to create a table in my DB with an ID that is autoincrement itself but whenever I try to add `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword to my query it tells me that :

> AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Here is my query:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_NOTETITLE + " TEXT, " + KEY_NOTECONTENT + " Text, "
            + KEY_STATUS + " INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

I have also tried to write `AUTO_INCREMENT` but then I got syntax error.

I found out that this is the source of the problem because whenever I try to remove `AUTOINCREMENT`, it works fine.

So... what do you think is the problem?

Comment: Related: If you want to create an auto-incrementing non-primary key column in SQLite (Google brought me here), then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69088585/1070129).

Answer (score 41):

You need to add a space between `KEY_ID` AND `INTEGER`

So change

```
+ KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
```

to

```
+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
```

Answer (score 8):

Create table with integer primary key no need to explicitly mention the AUTOINCREMENT

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
  a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  C TEXT
); 

Insert into t1(C) values("Hello");
```

Comment: Without autoincrement sqlite may reuse deleted ids.

Comment: @loshadvtapkah PRIMARY KEY will use unused integer greater than the last row id: source: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: @RameshKumar yes, and it doesn't mean it wouldn't reuse ids.  If I remove several records with the top ids, they will be reused.  In most of the cases it is not a problem at all, but even if application is keeping track on foreign keys checks, it is better to not have reused keys, to avoid one bug due to other bug.

Answer (score 2):

Create Table like this put some space before INTEGER ....

```
"CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> Parse error: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Because I used `TEXT` type with `PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  -- ↑↑↑↑
);
```

So, I used `INTEGER` type with `PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
);
```

[The doc](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html#the_autoincrement_keyword) says below:

> Any attempt to use `AUTOINCREMENT` on a WITHOUT ROWID table or on a column other than the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column results in an error.

In addition, if you use `AUTOINCREMENT` without `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT
          -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
);
```

Then, you get the error below:

> Parse error: near "autoincrement": syntax error