# Sqlite: how do I increment a row value by +1?

Tags: sqlite, android-cursor, content-values

I have a TOTALCOUNT table with a PK _id column and an integer column "CARDNUM".  I want to set the default value of CARDNUM to zero.  And then increment CARDNUM by +1 each time a new row is inserted into the database.  So 5 row inserts would produce 1,2,3,4,5 for rowids 1 to 5.  When I push the data to the individual CardViews in my RecyclerView I am only getting the default value of zero.  The first five CardViews should be showing the CARDNUM value so 1,2,3,4,5.  What am I missing here?

DBContract file:

```
...
public static final String TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT = "totalcount";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNTID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM = "cardnum";
    }
}

    A second table, not shown is called USERINPUTS.
```

DBHelper file:

```
...
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Set up the Column headings for USERINPUTS and TOTALCOUNT Tables.
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CARDNUM);

private static final String SQL_CREATE_CARDNUM =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT +
            "( "+ DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_COUNTID +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "+
            DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +
            " INTEGER);";

public void insertIntoTableTOTALCOUNT() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();

    String select = "Select * from "+ DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT;

    Cursor c =db.rawQuery(select, null);
    int cardnum=0;

    try {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            cardnum = c.getInt(1);
            cardnum++;
        }
    } finally {
        if(c !=null && !c.isClosed()){
            c.close();
        }
    }

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM,cardnum);
    db.insert(DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT,null,cv);

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    // Close the database.
    if(db.isOpen())
        db.close();
}

...
// Two Tables push the data to a RecyclerView list.
public List<UserData> getDataFromDB(){
    List<UserData> modelList = new ArrayList<>();

    String query = "SELECT *, (SELECT " + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +
            " from " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT +") from "
            + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_USERINPUTS +";";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Log.d("TAG", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));

        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    UserData userData = new UserData();
                    userData.setTodo(cursor.getString(1));
                    userData.setNote1(cursor.getString(2));
                    userData.setNote2(cursor.getString(3));
                    userData.setDuedate(cursor.getString(4));
                    userData.setDuetime(cursor.getString(5));
                    userData.setTimestamp(cursor.getLong(6));
                    userData.setCardnum(cursor.getInt(7));

                    modelList.add(0, userData);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } finally {
              if(cursor !=null && !cursor.isClosed()){
              cursor.close();
              }
          }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    return modelList;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of having a primary key value which is not autoincremented?

Comment: I am looking to have a column of values that increment by +1 with a default value of 0.  I am new to SQLite so not sure what the best way to go about this.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982173/sqlite-auto-increment-non-primary-key-field).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look...and I appreciate you coming back with additional advice.  My apologies for my venting, I did not mean to direct that.

Comment: I never thought you vented actually.  Your design may have some flaws, but at least now you have two ways to auto increment a column.

Comment: Unfortunately app crashes on trying to create the table so something is not correct.  String is:  "private static final String SQL_CREATE_CARDNUM =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT +
                "( "+ DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +
                   " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT )";"

Comment: I think SQLite doesn't let you use `AUTOINCREMENT` unless the field is _also_ the primary key.  So the link I provided is an alternative. Really, I think your database design needs some improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily by adding " **AUTOINCREMENT** " option when creating table and it will automatically incremented

or by your way ,, but you are missing when dealing with **Cursor** 
try this way

---

```
Cursor c =db.rawQuery(select, null);
    int cardnum=0;
c.moveToFirst();
while( c != null )
{
 cardnum = c.getInt(1);
            cardnum++;
c.moveToNext();
}
```

---

Comment: Android Studio warning says "Condition "(c != null)" is always true.

Comment: it will be always true untill the last row have value of your table , then moveToNext() method will return null cursor

Comment: App crashes.  Using my way from above, error message says "CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0" for the line "cardnum = c.getInt(1);"