# ef7 sqlite, configure identity column

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, auto-increment

i try to create sqlite db using EF7.
the class:

```
public class Item
{
    //primaery key, not identity
    public string id { get; set; }

    //not primery key, but needed autoincerment
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int numberInc { get; set; }
}
```

but in the table genereted `numberInc` its a normal column:

```
CREATE TABLE "VideoItem" (
    "id" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_VideoItem" PRIMARY KEY,
    "numberInc" INTEGER NOT NULL,
)
```

i also tried setting the column in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VideoItem>().Property(x => x.numberInc).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
```

but any effect.
iwm use `EntityFramework.Sqlite 7.0.0-rc1-final`.

Comment: is there an entry in your sqlite_sequence table for this table? Also, I have only found the combination PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT in sqlite syntax (https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/column-constraint.html), so this might be to avoid incorrect syntax.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, You're probably right ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/6982173/1271037 tnx!