# SQLAlchemy/FastAPI: TestClient how to test Sequence (using sqlite)

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm using the FastAPI TestClient as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-database/).  Works fine except for creating a resource since I'm using a sequence for the ID columns:

```
ItemID = Column(
    BigInteger,
    Sequence("item_id_seq"),
    index=True,
    primary_key=True,
    nullable=False,
)
```

I know sqlite does not support sequencer.  So it is just ignored.  But when creating an item I get a NULL constraint exception since the ID is never set.

Is there a workaround?  Is there an alternative SQL database for such tests?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `AUTOINCREMENT`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817038/how-can-i-create-a-sequence-in-sqlite

Comment: Thanks for the eye opener.  We don't really need the sequence using autoincrement works fine w/ both sqlite and MS SQL server.
Nevertheless it does not work with BigInteger and sqlite.  But here is a solution to handle both: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23175518/2606766

Comment: @rfkortekaas thanks a lot.  If rephrase your comment as an answer we could mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of @rfkortekaas (all credits go to him):
We now use *AUTOINCREMENT* instead of a *Sequence*.  Since this is the default when the primary_key is an integer the following is sufficient:

```
ItemID = Column(
    BigIntegerType,
    index=True,
    primary_key=True,
)
```

Since this does not apply for *BigInteger* and sqlite we use our own data type (*BigIntegerType*) thus using BigInteger on our MS SQL Server in production and Integer for sqlite for testing:

```
BigIntegerType = BigInteger()
BigIntegerType = BigIntegerType.with_variant(sqlite.INTEGER(), "sqlite")
```